# Combining csv files to but keeping separate columns in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two csv files (FileA.csv and FileB.csv), each with one column. I'm trying to combine them in to one csv file, but keeping two separate columns (then applying some conditional formatting afterwards). So far, I've only been able to append the two lists and end up with one column of all the data. Is there any way to have Column A with FileA.csv and then Column B with FileB.csv?
Thanks!

Comment: you have 2 csvs representing each time objects with one property only. to merge this you need to build a new object containg both attributes and export it as csv. but its hard to say  if this makes sense without knowing how the csv files do look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script below will concatenate the content of both files and print the lines side by side.

It is considering the same number of lines in both files, if it isn't your case, you have to apply a logic to print blank spaces or whatever you want to at that line/position.

**Code explanation:**

1. Get the content of each file and store it on a variable
2. Count the lines of file-a.csv
3. Print the number of lines (just to check it)
4. Iterate over each line

**code:**

```
$a_file = Get-Content file-a.csv
$b_file = Get-Content file-b.csv

gc .\file-a.csv | %{$a_lines++}

echo $a_lines
5

for($i=0; $i -lt $a_lines; $i++) {
    Add-Content -Path file-c.csv -Value ($a_file[$i] + ";" + $b_file[$i])
}
```

result:

> file a line 1 file b line 1
>
> file a line 2 file b line 2
>
> file a line 3 file b line 3
>
> file a line 4 file b line 4
>
> file a line 5 file b line 5

Comment: Thanks! That got exactly what I wanted! I'm trying to get this to export to csv file, but having some issues (again). Currently trying "$a_lines| Export-Csv C:\Temp\FINAL.csv" at the end of the loop. Sorry! I'm still new at Powershell and trying to learn along the way.

Comment: I gonna check it for you later. I have no experience at all with powershell. I did it as an exercise

Comment: @BrianSpringer I found the way to write the content to a file. I hope it help you

Comment: @btafelo Works exactly how I needed it to. Appreciate it!